# Is there a setting in (professional) laser printers to omit toner heating/fusing?

Tags: digital-printing

I'm experimenting with the toner transfer method for PCB and accidentally a jammed print-out of a plastic transparency was left "unheated" and the toner could be easily erased by the finger. Now I want to reproduce it because it is perfect for the toner transfer method. So anyone knows if there is a setting in laser printer to omit the stage of toner heating-fusing?

Comment: yes but that is proprietary laser specific info. ask manufacturer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper terms (at least in English) is toner "fusing" and the heating elements is called a "fuser." This may help you in your searches. I think the short answer is "no."

The longer answer is: by design the printer won't print without heat. You cannot simply cut the heating element without a software fault, but one might be able to replace the thermistor with a resistor to convince the laser printer to print the page instead of throwing an error. Or put something in-line so the thermistor thinks the fuser is hot. Alternatively one might hack the fuser in some way to move the heating element and sensor so that they heat and sense but don't contact the paper.

Obviously this is a big hack and potentially dangerous.